# PowerBI dynamically change column name in table visualization based on current date

Tags: date, dynamic, powerbi, rename

i have a table that has a date as column name (ex. 02/08/2023) referring to yesterday. when I crate a table and use this column it works fine until the next day because the table field cant find the column name anymore (now yesterday is 03/08/2023.

how can i dynamically change column name in the table visualization based on the date of yesterday? i need to show the date and not a text that says yesterday or 1 day ago.

[in the picture you can see eht column today which date will change every day i open the report. instead of today i want to see the actual date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udi5I.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.